# NPE when invoking getter of managed property

Tags: spring, jsf-2, nullpointerexception

I am learning Spring with Hibernate and am creating a movie rental application using JSF as front end framework.

I have an application scoped managed property in my registration bean which is view scoped. In the `register()` method to insert the user details in the database, I invoke the service locator implementation bean to get a reference to the required service implementation. However, I get an NPE when I invoke the getter of the service locator property.

Following are my managed beans...

**Registration Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RegistrationBean extends BaseBean implements Serializable
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -6449858513581500971L;

   private String userID;
   private String password;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String email;
   private String addressLine1;
   private String addressLine2;
   private String city;
   private String state;
   private String pincode;

   public RegistrationBean() {
      super();
   }

   // getter / setters...

   public String register() 
   {
      String nextPage = null;
      try {
         RegistrationDetails userDetails = ModelBuilder.populateRegistrationData(this);

         // NPE at this line. getServiceLocator() returns null
         int registrationID = getServiceLocator().getUserService().registerUser(userDetails);

         nextPage = "success";
      }
      catch (RegistrationException e) {
         LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
      }
      return nextPage;
   }
}
```

**Base Bean**

```
public class BaseBean
{
   @ManagedProperty("#{serviceLocator}")
   protected IServiceLocator serviceLocator;

   protected IServiceLocator getServiceLocator() {
      return serviceLocator;
   }

   public void setServiceLocator(IServiceLocator serviceLocator) {
      this.serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
   }
}
```

**Service Locator Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ServiceLocator implements IServiceLocator
{
   private static final String USER_SERVICE = "userService";

   public ServiceLocator() {
      super();
      final ServletContext sc = FacesUtils.getServletContext();
      this.webAppContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(sc);
      this.userService = (IUserService) webAppContext.getBean(USER_SERVICE);
   }

   private ApplicationContext webAppContext;

   private IUserService userService;

   @Override
   public IUserService getUserService() {
      return userService;
   }

   public ApplicationContext getWebAppContext() {
      return webAppContext;
   }
}
```

**And here is the stacktrace as seen in my Eclipse console**

```
Oct 14, 2012 10:28:39 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: #{registrationBean.register}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{registrationBean.register}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.clixflix.managedbeans.RegistrationBean.register(RegistrationBean.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 24 more
```

I am using

- JSF 2.1 (Mojarra)
- Hibernate 4.1
- Spring 3.2
- Tomcat 7
- Eclipse 3.7

Could someone please point out if I have missed something??

**UPDATE**: Spring config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

   <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="userDAO" class="com.clixflix.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl">
      <constructor-arg index="0" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="userService" class="com.clixflix.services.impl.UserService">
      <constructor-arg index="0" ref="userDAO" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: @BalusC - As I said, I am _learning_ Spring + Hibernate, so my design would be adhoc. But no, my service locator isn't a spring bean. The user service property it encapsulates, is a spring bean. I have added my spring configuration file. And I did read one article which uses JSF2.0 with Spring MVC but it was kinda confusing so right now I am just using dependency injection and the hibernate template provided by Spring ORM for the hibernate part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post helped me to make the code work : http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/jsf-2-primefaces-3-spring-3-hibernate-4.html

However, the code does not work if I keep the Registration Bean as `view scoped`. Can anyone please help me figure out the reason for the same?

UPDATE: Found the solution for the ViewScope issue : http://blog.harezmi.com.tr/spring-view-scope-for-jsf-2-users/

Comment: The last link here is broken. You may want to either fix that link or add the solution that actually worked for you. Otherwise, this answer is not worth reading at all. When you specify a link, quote at least some important points in your question and/or answer so that they can be useful to future visitors even though the link is broken.

Comment: @Vrushank :  May I know why is that `get()` method synchronized? I don't see this [here](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/) and [here](http://comdynamics.net/blog/109/spring3-jsf2-view-scope/). Is it mandatory? Additionally, the body of `registerDestructionCallback()`, `getConversationId()` and `getViewMap()` methods has been left blank there. Do these methods have some significance? When these methods need to be coded as shown in your last [link](http://blog.harezmi.com.tr/spring-view-scope-for-jsf-2-users/)?

Comment: P.S. This works fine for me (Primefaces 3.5, Spring 3.2.2). Thanks.

Comment: @Lion : It is not mandatory to synchronize the `get()` method unless you are expecting high concurrency. The other methods are part of the implementation contract so need to be overrriden, particluarly the destruction callbacks in order to mage the bean lifecycle properly.

Comment: @Vrushank : OK... well, but this is asked by Tiny :) :). You should notify him. thanks