# Primefaces datatable selected row not working using viewscope

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, nullpointerexception, viewstate

I am using JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 3.4.2, I have a datatable populated using lazy load.

When I view scope for managedbean, then datatable selectedRow gives null pointer exception.
If I use session scope then I could get selectedRow in managedbean.

I am using CDI Spring annotations for specifying scope. I have used [this](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/) method to create view scope.

*Update 1*

I have noticed another thing is using view scope when I paginate to second page and then comes back to first page, then I could get the selectedRow. If I select a row without paginating then I get null pointer exception.

JSF Page

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="req" lazy="true" value="#{emp.lazyModel}"
                paginator="true" rows="10" 
                             selection="#{emp.selectedRequest}"
                            selectionMode="single">                         
          <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{emp.onRowSelect}" />
```

ManagedBean

```
@Named("emp")
@Scope("view")
public class EmployeesManagedBean implements Serializable {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        initTable();
    }

    private void initTable() {
        lazyModel = new LazyRequestDataModel(requestList, requestService);
    }

    public LazyDataModel<Employee> getLazyModel() {
        return lazyModel;

    }
```

I am getting nullpointer exception at this line in `onRowSelect` method

```
 Emp emp = (Emp) event.getObject()); 
 System.out.println(emp.getEmpNo() );
```

Full error stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.test.managed.bean.RequestManagedBean.onRowSelect(RequestManagedBean.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:187)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:52)
    at org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent.processListener(SelectEvent.java:40)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1071)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this issue by using `@ViewAccessScoped` which is supported in CDI. Add the dependency in maven or directly download from http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/cdi/download.html and put it in classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-extcdi-core-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

One small problem still remains i.e. when application is deployed for the first time, I still do not get selected row value, for the subsequent selections I am able to get selected row value.

Comment: You should continue investigating that issue , cause eventually it should work right from the start and not after the first time

Comment: @Daniel I am not getting any clue on how it doesn't get selected row for first time.

Comment: How about modifying your `get()` and `remove()` methods slightly as mentioned [here](http://comdynamics.net/blog/109/spring3-jsf2-view-scope/) adding an extra conditional check in both of them?

Comment: P.S : This works for me but I'm not using CDI beans as you're doing.

Comment: @Tiny Basically it is Spring's view scope instead of CDI right?

Comment: Yes, it is view scope and the method you [link](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/) in your question works fine for me (with Primefaces 3.5, Spring 3.2.2) including row selection in `DataTable`,single and multiple row deletion, all CRUD operations are performed well as expected. Additionally, I don't see `NullPointerException` anymore. I'm however, currently following [this](http://blog.harezmi.com.tr/spring-view-scope-for-jsf-2-users/) more verbose approach found from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12903214/1391249) answer afterwords Thanks

Comment: Probably, I may encounter problems later but until now it is going well. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to provide rowKey attribute on datatable, if you want to work with selection.

Comment: If I add rowKey then I get exception `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getRowData(DataTable.java:798)
 at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decodeSingleSelection(SelectionFeature.java:46)` Besides I am not sure for PF 3.4.2 rowKey is required, see [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableComplex.jsf) for example.

Comment: This example has rowKey, I supposed you thought on example with lazy loading. That example doesn't have rowKey on tag, but they put it in LazyDataModel implementation. They wrote both getRowKey and getRowData methods. I have one theory about this:
You have some c: tags on page, or you have some binding attributes. It would be helpful if you provide whole xhtml code. I think this is the problem because you told that everything works fine with Session scoped bean.